# Selenium webdriver running issue

Tags: selenium

I am trying to running selenium webdriver using eclipse.Unfortunately i face the following issue:

[click here for the snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaqMZ.jpg)

and the code is,

```
package myproject; 

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver; 

public class MyClass { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub        
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "K:\\New folder\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe"); 
       WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); driver.get("http://only-testing-blog.blogspot.in"); 
      String i = driver.getCurrentUrl(); 
      System.out.println(i); driver.close(); 
   } 
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: yo can see in the images which i post

Comment: No, I can't. You need to explain what is the problem.

Comment: when i run the code as run as java application then ask select java application select type(?=any character,*=any String,TZ=TimeZone) dialog box open

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**
If you right click on your project and "Run as... Java application" and you have multiple main methods in your project, eclipse doesn't know which one to start so it asks which class. The solution is to right click on your **class** and "Run as...". After that you can just press "Run".

Comment: when i run the code as run as java application then ask select java application select type(?=any character,*=any String,TZ=TimeZone) dialog box open

Comment: @GauravMatapurkar format your code next time... this may be a stupid question but have your tried to select "MyClass - myproject"  from the Matching items ?

Comment: Yes I select myclass from given matching items but it always ask the same tto run the code

Comment: @GauravMatapurkari know th solution and will update my answer

Comment: Plz help me to get out of this

Comment: I have one main method in the class how can i fix the issue for the next program

Comment: @GauravMatapurkar im talking about the **Project** not the **Class**, the project is the folder with all the classes in it

Comment: If i right click on my project and then run as Java Application how can   i fix the same issue

Comment: delete the other main methods or start your application from the desired class, and as you can see all the classes listed under matching items  have a main method, always make a new Project for each application

Comment: I want to run my application Right Click->project->Run as Java Application

Comment: @GauravMatapurkar as long as you have multiple main **methods** in your project its not going to work!! I can see two classes with main methods on your image

Comment: I have One class with main method which is MyClass only

Comment: @GauravMatapurkar can you upload your project somewhere and share it with me? Just right click the project -> export -> Archive file

Comment: Plz give your email id

Comment: @GauravMatapurkar stackoverflow@trash-mail.com

Comment: I have sent project to given email id

Comment: @GauravMatapurkar Sorry, I can't help you with that, the only way i know how to solve it is like above (right click the class file -> Run As and then after that just press the green Run button in the toolbar)  or you might also try to configure your start settings with "myproject -> Run as.. -> Run Configurations" and have a look at the "Main class" Good luck

Comment: You do not know when Right Click project->Run as Java Application why does select java application pop uo box open